# Reusing or creating a google storage.Client()

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm working with Google Cloud Storage. One of its best practices is to reuse the clients. I've written several functions which I would like to be run with the possibility of not reusing the client.
The coder would be the one to decide that, by using the `reuse_cl` variable.

I was wondering why the following script does not work:

```
def test_storage(bucket_name,reuse_cl=True):
    if not reuse_cl:
        storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    list_blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    test_storage(BUCKET_NAME)
```

If I comment out the if in the test_storage, then everything works out fine. Is there a way of making the script work, and preserve the ability to create a client inside the function?

Comment: When you use the word 'function' - i.e. "I've written several functions..."- do you mean GCP cloud functions? In some cases you might be able to reuse a 'client' between a cloud function invocations - do you require this?

Comment: @al-dann functions similar to test_storage. My problem is not being able to create new clients. I would like my functions to also be used as stand-alone, without the need to create a client in the main if, i.e. I want my function to also work, if I comment out the line storage_client = storage.Client() in the main if.

Comment: I woudl rather define `def test_storage(bucket_name, storage_client=None):` and run with `test_storage(BUCKET_NAME, storage_client)` or `test_storage(BUCKET_NAME)` which would run `if not storage_client: storage_client = storage.Client()`

Comment: In most cases, there is little benefit to reusing clients. Is increased code complexity worth it? That depends on details not present in your question.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Can you please let us know if the above comments from Furas helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comments from @furas and @John Hanley for better visibility:

You should change the parameters expected in the function, so that can receive the client instead of a flag. You can take the following approach to do so:

`def test_storage(bucket_name, storage_client=None):`

And when invoking the function you can do so with either:
`test_storage(BUCKET_NAME, storage_client)` or

`test_storage(BUCKET_NAME)` and add something like this to the function: `if not storage_client: storage_client = storage.Client()`

This way, you will create a client when you don't receive it on the invocation. However, you have to take into consideration if reusing client brings you enough benefits, and if they outweigh increased code complexity making it worth it.